# Build works locally and fails in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a project in C Sharp which build correctly in my local machine ( as well as in the one from my colleagues ). But when we try to configure the pipeline in Azure, in the step of **Nuget restore** everything stops and we get an error message stating that package "A" is not compatible with netcore 2.2, as well as package B,C,D,etc.

Why is it possible to see this error in Azure but not in my local? The project is setup to use netcore 2.2 and builds fine in my local machine.

Comment: Did you clear any local package cache before rebuilding locally? Can you provide some more information? For example your `packages.config`, `nuget.config`, etc..?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I clear Nuget cache before pushing my repo to Azure. Also, even if I didn't, how can there be conflicting versions in Azure but not in my local? I ll try to upload my config when I'm closer to my laptop.

Comment: Are both environments using the same nuget repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it possible to see this error in Azure but not in my local? The project is setup to use netcore 2.2 and builds fine in my local machine.

This error can occur with an outdated version of nuget. The default version of NuGet running in the VSTS pipeline was not the latest one.

So, to resolve this issue, there is a [nuget version installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) task which you can run as part of your build step to upgrade the version of nuget running in your build pipeline:

[image]

Besides, if update nuget version not resolve this issue, please check the SDK version on the build agent is same as your local, you can use the task [Use .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops) to update the SDK version.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This was the issue. I was never going to connect the error message with this but nice you pointed out.